# Error to use 1.3 in sql query

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am using the following query.

```
select * from wp_rg_lead_detail where lead_id=5063 and field_number=cast(1.6 as decimal).
```

but it returns the field number 2 result instead of 1.6

Please let me know how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
select * from wp_rg_lead_detail where lead_id=5063 and field_number=cast(1.6 as decimal(2, 1))
```

You must specify number of digits in your decimal when casting, an number of digits after coma (I set them to 2 digits decimal with 1 after coma). You can easily test such casting by simply writing query:

```
SELECT Cast( 1.6 as decimal(2,1))
```

this will produce you effect of your casting. If you don't include (2,1) part, it will be automatically rounded to 2.

Comment: Well, you must a bit tune it up to work with YOUR data. maybe your field_number field consists of more digits than 2. Casting itself works with in phpMyAdmin (check alone casting query)

Comment: I have used this select * from wp_rg_lead_detail where lead_id=5063 and field_number=1.6 but it is showing empty result

Comment: Then check if the record you want to select HAS IN FACT lead_id that equals to 5063 AND field_number equal to 1.6 (in topic you specified 1.3)

Comment: It has to be 1 record, becouse of AND logic operator. If you want to select 2 of them, use OR insted of AND.

Comment: I am using the foreach loop , i wanna both records but every time it is showing empty result because every time it does not read the field number 1.3 and 1.6